# C# HtmlAgilityPack inner html dont change after appending node

Tags: c#, html, tree, html-agility-pack, nodes

In my C# i change loaded html, and need to get html document as plain text. But whenever i append new node to one of document's node, the inner html of root node doesn't change, even if the new node is successfully added. After debugging i noticed that only the parents of new node has the change in their InnerHtml property, for example:

```
HtmlDocument doc;
HtmlNode root doc.DocumentNode;
HtmlNode node2 = root.ChildNodes[1];
HtmlNode newNode = new HtmlNode(...);
node2.Append(newNode);
```

Having:

```
<root>
    <node1>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <node3>
        <node3>
        <newNode>
        </newNode>
    </node2>
</root>
```

node2.InnerHtml will be

```
        <node3>
        <node3>
        <newNode>
        </newNode>
```

but root.InnerHtml is

```
<root>
    <node1>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <node3>
        <node3>
    </node2>
</root>
```

How can i fix this right? ( i know i could manually update every document's node inner html, but common... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using method `WriteContentTo()` instead of using properties `InnerHtml` or `OuterHtml`